# How to toggle properties using an ASP.NET checkbox and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

The following code sets a chosen property of one element and toggles that element when a checkboxs checked value is changed.

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:CheckBox CssClass="Cb" RunAt="Server"/>
<asp:TextBox CssClass="Txt" RunAt="Server" ReadOnly="True"/>
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="Cb" type="checkbox"/>
<input class="Txt" type="text" readonly="true"/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".Cb").change(function() {
    $(".Txt").prop("readonly",!this.checked);
});
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/gKwbn/

---

**A PROBLEM**

When this code is executed with a ASP.NET asp:checkbox the result is not the same as when the code is executed with an input:checkbox.

With input:checkbox the readonly state toggles as:

**INITIAL STATE**

```
<input class="Txt" type="text" readonly="true"/>
```

**TOGGLE**

```
<input class="Txt" type="text"/>
<input class="Txt" type="text" readonly=""/>
```

With asp:checkbox the readonly state toggles as:

**INITIAL STATE**

```
<input class="Txt" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
```

**TOGGLE**

```
<input class="Txt" type="text" readonly=""/>
<input class="Txt" type="text" readonly=""/>
```

**UNDERSTANDING READONLY**

All the following are properies are valid for readonly to be set to true.

- readonly
- readonly=""
- readonly="true"
- readonly="readonly"

---

**MY QUESTIONS**

How to remove and then toggle the readonly property when using asp.net with jquery/javascript?

---

**EDITS**

The problem is the class is applied to the incorrect element when using an asp:checkbox.

THIS

```
<asp:CheckBox CssClass="Cb" RunAt="Server"/>
```

RENDERS IN THE BROWSER AS

```
<span class="Cb"><input id="ctl01" type="checkbox" name="ctl01" /></span>
```

**THE SOLUTION**

Target the asp:checkbox using ID and not class.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CBID" CssClass="Cb" RunAt="Server"/>

$("#<%= CBID.ClientID %>").change(function() {
    $(".Txt").prop("readonly", this.checked ? "" : "readonly");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not completely misunderstanding your question, you can use this instead...

```
$(".Cb").change(function() {
    $(".Txt").prop("readonly", this.checked ? "" : "readonly");
});
```

That will set the `readonly` property to either `readonly` or empty, depending on the checkbox state.

**[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gKwbn/2/)**

**Edit:** Further to your update, you can either add the class to the checkbox like this...

```
<asp:CheckBox class="Cb" RunAt="Server"/>
```

or you can refer to it by ID...

```
$("#ctl01").change(function()...
```

or by name...

```
$("input[name=ctl01]").change(function()...
```

or by the fact that it's in the span...

```
$(".Cb input:checkbox").change(function()...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Archer. Your code is correct but again does not work when applied to an asp:checkbox.

Comment: There must be something else amiss here as I've just done it with an ASP.Net checkbox and it *does* work.  It's still just a checkbox when the page is rendered.  What makes you say it doesn't work - what is actually going wrong?

Comment: You've added the class `Cb` to the checkbox's containing span, not the checkbox itself.  Put that on the checkbox instead and it should fix your problem :)

Comment: Aha you spotted the issue. It does not however solve my problem. Please see my edits at above.

Comment: Many Thanks Archer. I have edited my question to accomodate the answer. I targeted the checkbox by ID instead of class.

Comment: @Archer - I have a similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/40431308/1735836 and I would love to get your input.  :-)