# JavaScript separate from html file - how to cleverly toggle enabled checkbox and buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Newbie Alert!

I'm trying to be clever.  When user checks the check box, I want all the buttons in the div to be disabled and when the user unchecks the check box, I want all the buttons to be enabled.  However when user makes a button selection and a list is displayed, until user selects the Done button (not shown), I want everything (checkbox and buttons) in the div to be disabled.  When user clicks the Done button, all (checkbox and buttons) in the div will become enabled again.

See the toggleFruitButtons function at the bottom of the question for details in comments of what I want to do.

**Inside .cshtml file:**

```
<div id="fruit">
     <input type="ckeckbox" id="SearchType_All" /> All
     <input type="button" id="SearchType_Apples" value="Search Apples" />
     <input type="button" id="SearchType_Oranges"  value="Search Oranges" />
     <input type="button" id="SearchType_Pears"  value="Search Pears" />
     <input type="button" id="SearchType_Grapes"  value="Search Grapes" /> 
</div>
```

**In the .js file:**

```
var jQuery = {
     jSearchType_All: $('#SearchType_All'),
     jSearchType_Apples: $('#SearchType_Apples'),
     jSearchType_Oranges: $('#SearchType_Oranges'),
     jSearchType_Pears: $('#SearchType_Pears'),
     jSearchType_Grapes: $('#SearchType_Grapes')
},
toggleFruitButtons;

//Bind events
jQueryVar.jSearchType_All.on("click", toggleFruitButtons);
jQueryVar.jSearchType_Apples.on("click", toggleFruitButtons);
jQueryVar.jSearchType_Oranges.on("click", toggleFruitButtons);
jQueryVar.jSearchType_Pears.on("click", toggleFruitButtons);
jQueryVar.jSearchType_Grapes.on("click", toggleFruitButtons);
```

**Here is my question:**

```
toggleFruitButtons = function() {
     // Is there a clever way to loop through both checkbox and
     // each button and set each's enabled/disabled to opposite?
}
```

Of course, I think I can do the following:

```
jQueryVar.jSearchType_Apples.prop("enabled", true ? false : true);
jQueryVar.jSearchType_Oranges.prop("enabled", true ? false : true);
jQueryVar.jSearchType_Pears.prop("enabled", true ? false : true);
jQueryVar.jSearchType_Grapes.prop("enabled", true ? false : true);
```

But is there a way to loop through each and make its enabled value **!** its enabled value?

Example in pseudo code:

```
for each
     this.button.enabled = !this.button.enabled;
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, but you can simplify the enable/disable all toggle like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5n2ps2j8/

Comment: I like it!  That does it if the user selects the All checkbox.  I think I can do something similar for disabling all the siblings when user selects a button (i.e., Apples) and enters a bunch of data for a report.  Then enabling all the siblings to reset the form when the user is finished with the current selection.  :-)

Comment: Hey, Rory!  +1 for showing me JSFiddle.